# Instance method unable to read class instance variables

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class

Problem: Variables from a class are being overlooked somehow when the method is called from a different class.

Basically: I have Class A, Class B. I also have Method A, Method B each in their respective classes.

When calling Method A from Class B Method B, I can NSLog values fine, however I cannot access an NSMutableArray contained within Class A. There is my issue.

```
// Class B
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
        foodListingObj = [[FoodListing alloc] initWithNibName:@"FoodListing" bundle:nil];
    }


    return self;
}    

- (void)toggleImage //Method B in Class B {

    [foodListingObj didToggle:self.indexOfToggledCell];
    }

    // Method in Class A
    - (void)didToggle:(NSIndexPath *)toggledIndexPath{
        //[_toggledIndexArray addObject:toggledIndexPath];
          [_toggledIndexArray addObject:@"Anything"];
    }

    // Method in Class A
    - (void)checkArray{

          // Log the count of the array
          // it always says 1 because I intialize the array
          // then add an an object like so [_toggledIndexArray addObject@"hi"];
         // in my ViewDidLoad Method. Hence it appears that the array is still around
          // (not deallocated), but yet my method cannot seem to touch it... 
          NSLog(@"%i",[_toggledIndexArray count]); 
    }

     // dealloc for Class A
    - (void)dealloc{
          // I release the array among other things
          [_toggledIndexArray release];
    }
```

The array (_toggledIndexArray) is a property declared in the header, and is initialized in Class A's viewDidLoad with

```
_toggledIndexArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

The error is the fact that Method A does not seem to affect the array for a reason unknown to me.

Answer (score 3):

From the code above, it looks like your problem is that you are creating a new instance of FoodListing each time your `toggleImage` method is called.

Is this really what you intend to do? If it is, ViewDidLoad isn't going to get called in this case, since you are just `alloc`ing and `init`ing the view controller as opposed to using `initWithNibName`, so unless you are doing something in your custom loadView method, there isn't going to be a view that is loaded.

However, I don't expect you do want to create a new instance each time, the implication from your code is that the FoodListing object already exists and has the array populated already.

So, in whatever "class b" is, declare a property of type FoodListing. Set this to your FoodListing view controller (this will be either when class b is created or presented, or when the FoodListing object is first created, you havent given enough context for me to say). Call the methods on the object held in the property instead of creating a new one.

Comment: I edited my question above with some modified code for testing. Does that help you answer the question any? From doing some more tests just now, I realize that I cannot perform any functions within the didToggle method. Calling it from my toggleImage Class (Class B) seems to cause the issues. And thanks a lot I really appreciate your speedy and helpful responses!

Comment: Thanks for updating the code. My answer remains the same :). Why are you instantiating a new FoodListing object every time? "class b" needs to have a property or ivar pointing to the "real" instance of class A.

Comment: Ah I understand what you're saying now. How do you point to an instance of a class using a property within Class B? Once again, thanks for your help!

Comment: I've updated the answer, it's hard to be more specific without knowing what class b is and where it sits in your application. If you're after actual code then let me know but you shouldn't really need me to tell you how to declare properties ;)

Comment: Ok so Class B is a singleton class which holds methods so that when an image is toggled in Class A (a class with a view which is indeed loaded up and able to be interacted with), Class B performs Method B above. In Class B can I point to the initialized Class A by doing the following: Class B's init method: (property defined in .h) foodListingObj = [[FoodListing alloc] initwithnibname:@"FoodListing.xib"]

Comment: Alright I think the question then boils down to the following: in a singleton class, how do I retrive the pointer to an instance of Class A, so that I can send a message (call the method) from that particular instance of Class A. Could you please explain that? Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you already have the pointer - foodListingObj declared in your singletons .h file? Just use that - so in your method B above, just get rid of the first line.

Comment: foodListingObj is a property declared in the .h file as a regular property with (nonatomic, retain). Does that look better? It still does not seem to be pointing the instance of Class A however....

Comment: If thats the case, then your init method for the singleton shouldn't have the alloc / init there either. You should only be creating food listing once in your entire program, either from a nib (if its your root controller or part of a tab bar) or programmatically somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain the FoodListing object in Class B as class variable and not always alloc/init it in toggleImage function. Perhaps do

```
if(self.foodListing==nil) { //alloc/init it}else{ //do your thing here.}
```